# F# - Sort Sequence Using Ordinal Ranks

Tags: csv, sorting, f#, ordinal

I have a sequence, generated by CsvProvider:

```
RD;RT;RC;RDT;RG;H;HA;HS;RSP;RFP;RCT;RPZ;HR;HT;RCID
Schema="String,String,String,String,String,String,int,String,String,String,int,String,int,String,String"
```

that may contain equal ranks in "e:int" position.

```
module SOQN =

   open System

   let ordinalRanks input =
      input
      // |> Seq.sortBy (fun (_, _, _, _, e, _) -> e)
      |> Seq.groupBy (fun (a, b, c, _, e, _) -> (a, b, c, e))
      |> Seq.mapi (fun i a b c d e f -> (a, b, c, d, i + 1, f))

   [<EntryPoint>]
   let main() = 
      let input = seq [ (2107, "HVST", "1315", "Alpha", 1, "JS");
                        (2107, "HVST", "1315", "Beta", 2, "ASC");
                        (2107, "HVST", "1315", "Gamma", 2, "ASC");...
                        (2237, "ABCD", "0905", "Pi", 1, "ABC");
                        (2237, "ABCD", "0905", "Sigma", 1, "CDE");
                        (2237, "ABCD", "0905", "Delta", 2, "EFG");...
                      ]

      let output = ordinalRanks input
      printfn "%A" output

// Actual Output
// seq [ (2107, "HVST", "13-15", "Alpha", 1, "JS");
//       (2107, "HVST", "13-15", "Beta", 2, "ASC");
//       (2107, "HVST", "13-15", "Gamma", 2, "ASC");...] 
//       (2237, "ABCD", "0905", "Pi", 1, "ABC");
//       (2237, "ABCD", "0905", "Sigma", 1, "CDE");
//       (2237, "ABCD", "0905", "Delta", 2, "EFG");...

// Expected Output
// seq [ (2107, "HVST", "13-15", "Alpha", 1, "JS");
//       (2107, "HVST", "13-15", "Beta", 2, "ASC");
//       (2107, "HVST", "13-15", "Gamma", 3, "ASC");...]
//       (2237, "ABCD", "0905", "Pi", 1, "ABC");
//       (2237, "ABCD", "0905", "Sigma", 2, "CDE");
//       (2237, "ABCD", "0905", "Delta", 3, "EFG");...
//
```

How do I sort using [Ordinal Ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Ordinal_ranking_(%221234%22_ranking)). Note that the rankings are within groups determined by the first three positions. Please advise?

```
// RD;RT;RC;RDT;RG;H;HA;HS;RSP;RFP;RCT;RPZ;HR;HT;RCID
let sortedData (inputCsv: String) = 
    let csvInput = Sample2Sort.Load(inputCsv)
    let csvHeaders = [| sprintf "%s" ((csvInput.Headers.Value) |> String.concat ";") |]
    let csvOutput = 
        csvInput.Rows
        |> Seq.filter (fun row -> row.RFP > 0)
        |> Seq.sortBy (fun row -> (DateTime.Parse(row.RD)), row.RC, row.RT, row.RFP)
        // |> Seq.groupBy (fun (a, b, c, _, _, _) -> (a, b, c))
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun (a, b, c, _, _, _) -> (row.RD, row.RC, row.RT))
        // |> Seq.collect (fun (_, group) -> group |> Seq.mapi (fun i (a, b, c, d, _, f) -> a, b, c, d, i + 1, f))
        |> Seq.collect (fun (_, group) -> 
            group |> Seq.mapi (fun i (a, b, c, d, _, f) -> 
                row.RCID, row.RC, ((row.RD, " ", row.RT) |> String.Concat)), row.RH, i + 1, row.HT)
    (csvHeaders, csvOutput)
```

Comment: I don't understand this requirement fully: "Note that the rankings are within groups determined by the first three positions.". For example if one item in the group has `..."AVST", "13-15"...`, another has `..."HVST", "13-15"...` and another has `..."HVST", "13-10"...`, which comes first and on what basis? You might find it easier to reason about this by using a `groupBy` function first, manipulating subgroups in their order of precedence, then flattening?

Comment: @drkmtr, I have made some changes to the original code that gives me the ranking I require but does not return the sequence which I expected?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue with your approach is that you do not correctly handle the fact that `groupBy` turns a sequence of values into a sequence of sequences of values - it returns a list of groups where each groups contains all the elements in the group.

Your first use of `groupBy` is correct, but I believe you need to use only `a, b, c` as your grouping key. After grouping, you can use `collect` to get a flat list as the result. You need to move your `mapi` function call inside the lambda and run it on all elements of the group:

```
let ordinalRanks input =
  input
  |> Seq.groupBy (fun (a, b, c, _, _, _) -> (a, b, c))
  |> Seq.collect (fun (_, group) ->
    group |> Seq.mapi (fun i (a, b, c, d, _, f) ->
        a, b, c, d, i + 1, f))
```

I'm not exactly sure how you want to use the existing order `e`. This snippet just ignores it, but it gives the right result for your sample input.

Comment: Tomas, you are correct that it works for my toy problem. However, the difficulty I have is that I am retrieving 180,000 records from a CSV file using **CsvProvider** and need to generate a `seq<int * string * string * string * int * string>` for onward processing. See the additional function _sortedData_ at the end of the original question for clarification.

Comment: @matekus I'm not sure what your question is now - can you give a small executable example that illustrates what's wrong?

Comment: Tomas, In the function _sortedData_ above, what do I replace  `(a, b, c, _, _, _)` with in `|> Seq.groupBy (fun (a, b, c, _, _, _) -> (row.RD, row.RC, row.RT))`. For example, do I need to enter all the row columns? Similar issue with `|> Seq.collect (fun (_, group) -> group |> Seq.mapi (fun i (a, b, c, d, _, f) -> row.RCID, row.RC, ((row.RD, " ", row.RT) |> String.Concat)), row.RH, i + 1, row.HT)`.

Comment: @matekus If your question is not about ordering, but about using CSV type provider, then you should open a new question - answering how to change a field value in a provided type would not fit in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Tomas, I was able to solve my real-world problem based on your solution to my toy problem above.

```
// RD;RT;RC;RDT;RG;H;HA;HS;RSP;RFP;RCT;RPZ;HR;HT;RCID
let sortedData inputCsv = 
    let csvInput = Sample.Load(inputCsv)
    let csvHeaders = [| sprintf "%s" ((csvInput.Headers.Value) |> String.concat ";") |]
    let csvOutput = 
        csvInput.Rows
        |> Seq.filter (fun row -> row.RFP > 0)
        |> Seq.sortBy (fun row -> (DateTime.Parse(row.RD)), row.RC, row.RT, row.RFP)
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> (row.RD, row.RC, row.RT))
        |> Seq.collect (fun (_, group) -> 
            group |> Seq.mapi (fun i row -> 
                               row.RCID, row.RC, 
                               ((row.RD, " ", row.RT) |> String.Concat)), 
                               row.RH, i + 1, row.HT)
    (csvHeaders, csvOutput)
```

Thanks once again for both your patience and the benefit of your expertise.